# How to get the brightness level from the camera Android

Tags: android, camera, android-sensors, brightness

I want to get the brightness level from the Android camera.

I need to display the light level detected by the Android camera, is there any posibility to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private final SensorManager mSensorManager;
private final Sensor mLightSensor;
private float mLightQuantity;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Obtain references to the SensorManager and the Light Sensor 
    sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    lightSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);

    // Implement a listener to receive updates 
    SensorEventListener listener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            lightQuantity = event.values[0];
        } 
    } 

    // Register the listener with the light sensor -- choosing 
    // one of the SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_* constants. 
    sensorManager.registerListener( 
            listener, lightSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I already did that the problem is that he does not fit on this method onSensorChanged !